# jquery object as parameter to function

Tags: json, function, object, parameter-passing

This is my jquery response:

```
[ 

    { "depot":
      { 
       "id": "D1",
        "intersection": {
            "first": "Markham",
            "second": "Lawrence"
        },
        "address": {
            "number": "25",
            "street": "Cougar Court",
            "city": "Scarborough",
            "province": "ON",
            "postal_code": "M1J"
        } 
     },
     "vehicle": [

            {
                "id": "V1",
                "depot_id": "D1",
                "model": "Ford Focus",
                "price": "45",
                "km_per_litre": "15",
                "cargo_cu_m": "YES",
                "category": "Compact car",
                "image": "www.coolcarz.com"
            }

                ,

            {
                "id": "V2",
                "depot_id": "D1",
                "model": "Honda Civic",
                "price": "45",
                "km_per_litre": "150",
                "cargo_cu_m": "YES",
                "category": "Compact car",
                "image": "www.coolcarz.com"
            }

                ,

            {
                "id": "V8",
                "depot_id": "D1",
                "model": "Pontiac Aztek",
                "price": "10",
                "km_per_litre": "6",
                "cargo_cu_m": "YES",
                "category": "SUV",
                "image": "www.nocoolcarz.com"
            }

                ,

            {
                "id": "V12",
                "depot_id": "D1",
                "model": "Chevrolet Impala",
                "price": "45",
                "km_per_litre": "12",
                "cargo_cu_m": "YES",
                "category": "Standard car",
                "image": "www.coolcarz.com"
            }

                ,

            {
                "id": "V29",
                "depot_id": "D1",
                "model": "Nissan Leaf",
                "price": "150",
                "km_per_litre": "0",
                "cargo_cu_m": "YES",
                "category": "Electronic Car",
                "image": "www.coolcarz.com"
            }

        ]
    }

     ,

    { "depot":
      { 
       "id": "A1",
        "intersection": {
            "first": "Markham",
            "second": "Lawrence"
        },
        "address": {
            "number": "25",
            "street": "Cougar Court",
            "city": "Scarborough",
            "province": "ON",
            "postal_code": "m1J"
        } 
     },
     "vehicle": [

        ]
    }

  ]
```

What I want to do is that at some point in my code, when I have received this response data, I want to pass , say data[0] or or data[0].vehicle[1] to a function 
The way I am doing it now is:

```
function(data) {
    var items = [];
    for( i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        items.push('<b>' + data[i].depot.intersection.first+"-"+ data[i].depot.intersection.second + " depot has following cars:"+ '</b>');
        for( k=0; k<data[i].vehicle.length;k++){
            str = '<li> <a href="#" onClick="moreInfo('+data+')">' +       data[i].vehicle[k].category +"</a>, $"+ data[i].vehicle[k].price +' a day </li>';

                                    items.push(str);
```

in effect I am trying to create a hyperlink (with vehicle category as text), and when user clicks on this hyperlink, I want to pass on the vehicle information array to a new function  called moreInfo that does its job. Rit now when I do this and click the hyperlink, I see the error

```
missing ] after element list
timepass([object Object],[object Object]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Remove 2 square brackets from  beginning and end of your json code and use use it as an object not as an array.

What you did was creating an array of objects not JSON object

Comment: This is incorrect. Valid JSON can have either an object (`{}`) or array (`[]`) as its topmost object. See the very beginning of [the RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt?number=4627): "A JSON text is a serialized object or array. `JSON-text = object / array`"

Comment: I am not saying it is incorrect Just suggesting to use Object Notation instead of Array notation. Sorry if I am making this confusing

Comment: WooDzu can you be more specific?

Comment: change all square brackets to round ones in your Json notation (or generator's code), then iterate through the parsed object exactly as you do with only one difference, use loop for(depot in data). There are no methods in the object, so that you can safely use it.